# How to add a column from source table into destination table when the data or column is currently not in the destination table

Tags: sql, ssis

I have a column that is called "organization" in my source table. I want to put that column into my destination table that currently doesn't have this data or column.I also want to make sure that each organization goes with the correct data in my table. I can do this with a join in sql server but I want to physically add that column and data into the destination table where I want have to query a join each time to see that one column.

Comment: Why not a view? Write the join once, use as needed without maintaining denormalized data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to physically add the column to the table. SSIS does not handle this functionality natively - it is an ETL tool.